# How to have multiple outputs for 1 oninput

Tags: html

I want to display 2 prices that change as the number of hours are changed by the user. I have almost no experience in HTML so I'm struggling with this piece of code. The "result" output works fine, but the "wedding" output doesn't change at all.

```
<form oninput="result.value=parseInt(b.value)*parseInt(150)+parseInt(499)">
<form oninput="wedding.value=parseInt(b.value)*parseInt(150)+parseInt(599)">
<form><input max="12" min="2" name="b" type="number" value="3" />
<table style="width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Price</td>
<td><strong>$<output name="result">949</output></strong></td>
<td><strong>$<output name="wedding">949</output></strong></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add multiple statements to one `oninput` property like

```
<form oninput="result.value=parseInt(b.value)*parseInt(150)+parseInt(499);wedding.value=parseInt(b.value)*parseInt(150)+parseInt(599)">
```